# CUDA gridDim, blockDim and threadIdx

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, gpu

This is a conceptual question. In CUDA, gridDim, blockDim and threadIdx can be 1D, 2D or 3D. I wonder, how are their 2D and 3D versions interpreted?

In more details, does CUDA think of multi-dimensional gridDim, blockDim and threadIdx just as a linear sequence, in the same way that C stores multi-dimensional array? If not, how should we interpret multi-dimensional gridDim, blockDim and threadIdx?

Thanks.

**Edit 1.**
This question is not a duplicated one. I actually have come across the referred question. It asks about the order of execution of the GPU threads, not their layouts, as this one does.

**Edit 2.**
Also, the answer to this question can be found at http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#thread-hierarchy. Thank you @talonmies, for the reference. To sum it up, multi-dimensional gridDim, blockDim and threadIdx is for convenience purposes. They can be interpreted just like a column major ordered multi-dimensional array.

Comment: What do you mean by *how are their 2D and 3D versions interpreted?* ? Could you expand your question a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting directly from the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz3pNAYmjME)

> The index of a thread and its thread ID relate to each other in a
>   straightforward way: For a one-dimensional block, they are the same;
>   for a two-dimensional block of size (Dx, Dy),the thread ID of a thread
>   of index (x, y) is (x + y Dx); for a three-dimensional block of size
>   (Dx, Dy, Dz), the thread ID of a thread of index (x, y, z) is (x + y
>   Dx + z Dx Dy).

So, yes the logical thread numbering in the programming model is sequential, with then the x dimension varying fastest, then the y dimension, then the z dimension. This applies both to thread numbering within blocks and block numbering within a grid. The numbering is analogous to [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) ordered multi-dimensional arrays, although the actual `threadIdx` and `blockIdx` variables themselves are just structures reflecting internal thread and block identification words assign by the scheduler to each thread or block.

You should note that numbering implied by  `threadIdx` and `blockIdx` are just for programmer convenience and don't imply anything about execution order of threads on the GPU.